# Invoke-RestMethod : 403 Forbidden

Tags: powershell

I try to download a txt file from an URL with my logged on pc username. Manually works but not by ps1. My code is the following:

```
$cuser = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName
$source = "https://xxx/$cuser.txt"
$destination = "C:\yyyy\$cuser.txt"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $destination
```

:( thanks for your  support

That my file was downloaded on my local folder.

Comment: [Edit] the question and include the actual 403 error message _as text_, do not paste an image. Those are hard to read.

Comment: What is your error? Can you paste the message received? Thanks!